# Add click event of img src tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in HTML,

I have 2 HTML pages `page1` and `Page2`

**Page1:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IOS_landing_V02</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (IOS_landing_V02.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1024" height="768" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="IOS_landing_V02_01.jpg" width="1024" height="20" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="IOS_landing_V02_02.jpg" width="1024" height="112" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="IOS_landing_V02_03.jpg" width="1024" height="422" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="IOS_landing_V02_04.jpg" width="1024" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="IOS_landing_V02_05.jpg" width="1024" height="213" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

On click of last img `(src="IOS_landing_V02_05.jpg")` i want to load another HTMl page i.e `Page2`

How to do this ?

Comment: Wrap the last image with anchor tag with href pointing to second page

Comment: Use link-tags <a> </a> around the image if you need it to be a link. Or do you need the javascript "onClick" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the last `img` inside a link like this :

```
<a href="pathToPage2.html">
  <img src="IOS_landing_V02_05.jpg" width="1024" height="213" alt="">
</a>
```

Now clicking on it, will load `page2`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your  `img` tag with `a` anchor tag that will redirect you.

```
<a href="page2.html"><img src="IOS_landing_V02_05.jpg" width="1024" height="213" alt=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way: Wrap your image with `<a>` tag, then add a link to your second page using the `href` attribute.

```
<td>
        <a href="page2.html">  
            <img src="IOS_landing_V02_05.jpg" width="1024" height="213" alt="">  
       </a>  
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set on click event for your image like this:

```
<img src="IOS_landing_V02_05.jpg" width="1024" height="213" alt="" onclick='newhtml()'>

// Function in head part
<script>
function Previewmode()
{
// load new html page
   window.open("http://newpage.html");   
}   
</script>
```